# Is it possible to use PS4 remote play on PC while someone else uses another account to watch videos on YouTube?

Tags: pc, ps4, ps-remote-play

Is it possible for me to use Windows PS4 remote play to play my games while someone else uses their profile on the PS4 to watch videos on YouTube, for example?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! If the answer below solved your problem please consider accepting it clicking the green tick

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, Remote Play screencasts PS4 output on another device, so what you will se on your device will be the actual PS4 screen.
Logging in with another account on your PS4 will show the other user's home and games, hence that screen will be mirrored on the remote device.

This is also confirmed on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/playstation/comments/12fwwcv/remote_play_while_console_is_used/):

> No. Remote play is remote controlling the console. You can’t do it while someone else is controlling it, you’re both sharing the same screen.